# How Local binary pattern's feature vector can be used for classification?

Tags: matlab

[cancer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGC1e.jpg)

[non-cancer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWRJ8.jpg)

I am working on a project for classification of skin cancer.I used built in MATLAB function `extractLBPFeatures()` for texture analysis.
I used 'false' in the parameters.I got a vector of 10 elements.But I failed to differentiate cancerous image from non-cancerous images.Because i saw that the values are similar for both of the case if the region of interest are closed (means almost same area).For small region i got small value ,for big region i got bigger value.What should i do to classify?

```
clc;    
close all; 
imtool close all; 
clear;
fontSize=10;
%Input image from current directory...
[file path]=uigetfile('.jpg','Select Image from the folder');
temp=[path file];
a=imread(temp);
a=imresize(a,[300 300]);
mkr=a;
%convert to gray scale image...
im=rgb2gray(a);
%a = imresize(a,[200 200]) 
m1 = im2double(a);
%im= imadjust(im);
%DullRazor technique for hair removal
se = strel('disk',5);
hairs = imbothat(im,se);
BW = hairs > 15;
BW2 = imdilate(BW,strel('disk',2));
replacedImage = roifill(im,BW2);
%filtering for removing artifacts..
replacedImage=medfilt2(replacedImage);
grayImage=replacedImage;

%Applying Otsu thresholding method....
level=graythresh(replacedImage);
a=im2bw(replacedImage,level);

%Hole fills...
a=imfill(~a,'holes');

%Labeling the image
a=bwlabel(a);

%Selecting the biggest region ..
s  = regionprops(a,'Area');
[maxValue,index] = max([s.Area]);
I=bwareaopen(a,maxValue);

%Morphological closing operation..
se = strel('disk',5);
I= imclose(I,se);
figure,imshow(I);
grayImage(~I)=nan;
figure,
imshow(grayImage);

lbp= extractLBPFeatures(grayImage,'Upright',false);
disp(lbp);
```